# Simple plot in LaTeX using gnuplot

Tags: diagrams, miktex, gnuplot

I would like to plot `sin(x)` on a LaTeX document (an article) by using `gnuplot` commands programmatically inside the document.

I am aware that you can save the plot as a `.tex` file and then insert it in the document using `\input{}`. However this is not what I am asking for. I would like to learn how to generate the plot inside the document source code.

This is the plot that I get when I use the gnuplot console, so this is the result I am expecting to get on my document too.

[image: gnuplot sin(x)]

I am using MiKTeX and TeXstudio, though this last is probably not relevant.

Comment: You might benefit from searching for, and looking at some of the other questions regarding gnuplot.  For instance http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/gnuplot-epslatex

Comment: What about the below answer is not an answer to your question? To me, your problem seems to have been solved by erik.

Comment: @hooy When I run the code provided in erik's answer I get an error (you can read about it on my comment), so I won't mark the question as answered until I get some working code. Did you run the code?

Answer (score 2):

The `pgfplots` package has an `\addplot gnuplot` command, which uses gnuplot to do the calculation and then import the data for plotting by `pgfplots`. In the following example, the first function is drawn in blue, the second in red.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot gnuplot {sin(x)};
  \addplot {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. What is the red line supposed to be? Why do you emphasize the fact that there are two functions? Can you tell me about them?

Comment: @Cebri I think the second line illustrates that `tikz` `sin(x)` expects `x` in degrees, not radians. Hence `sin(deg(x))` produces same red as gnuplot blue.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for your inputs, the red line indeed corresponds to the `sin(x)` in degrees.

Comment: When I run erik's code on my editor and compile, I get the following error: `line 7: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'plotTest.pgf-plot.tab<file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. \addplot gnuplot {sin(x)};
: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} into your preamble.` The output image that I get only shows the red sine but not the blue one. Anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: @Cebri Did you try adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` to your preamble? If that didn't work, perhaps this question will be helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120218/24974

Comment: @Cebri It would seem as if you are not running `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape` enabled.

Comment: @hooy Adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`  on the preamble only removes the warning but not the error: `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'gnuplot_test2.pgf-ploplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. \addplot gnuplot {sin(x)};`

Comment: @Cebri I never suggested you needed to include that. I said it looked as if you weren't using the `-shell-escape` flag with `pdflatex` in order to call an external application (`gnuplot`).